# generating HChaCha20 internal state with existant ChaCha20 implementation

Tags: openssl

In [RFC7539 § 2.3.2. Test Vector for the ChaCha20 Block Function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.3.2) it shows the "ChaCha state at the end of the ChaCha20 operation". I'm able to get that with PHP 7.2.8 and OpenSSL thusly:

```
<?php

$key = implode(range(chr(0x00), chr(0x1f)), '');
$nonce = "\x00\x00\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x4a\x00\x00\x00\x00";
$counter = 1;

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
    str_repeat("\0", 64),
    'chacha20',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    pack('V', $counter) . $nonce
);

$ciphertext = bin2hex(preg_replace('#(.)(.)(.)(.)#', '$4$3$2$1', $ciphertext));
$ciphertext = chunk_split($ciphertext, 8, ' ');
$ciphertext = chunk_split($ciphertext, 32 + 4);

echo $ciphertext;
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with the draft for XChaCha [§ 2.2.1. Test Vector for the HChaCha20 Block Function](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-00#section-2.2.1) and am having some difficulty. My code:

```
<?php

$key = implode(range(chr(0x00), chr(0x1f)), '');
$nonce = "\x00\x00\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x4a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x31\x41\x59\x27";

// $nonce = strrev(substr($nonce, 0, 4)) . substr($nonce, 4);

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
    str_repeat("\0", 64),
    'chacha20',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $nonce
);

$ciphertext = bin2hex(preg_replace('#(.)(.)(.)(.)#', '$4$3$2$1', $ciphertext));
$ciphertext = chunk_split($ciphertext, 8, ' ');
$ciphertext = chunk_split($ciphertext, 32 + 4);

echo $ciphertext;
```

Looking at the draft it seems like this should work, per this chart:

```
              cccccccc  cccccccc  cccccccc  cccccccc
              kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk
              kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk
              bbbbbbbb  nnnnnnnn  nnnnnnnn  nnnnnnnn

       ChaCha20 State: c=constant k=key b=blockcount n=nonce

              cccccccc  cccccccc  cccccccc  cccccccc
              kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk
              kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk  kkkkkkkk
              nnnnnnnn  nnnnnnnn  nnnnnnnn  nnnnnnnn

             HChaCha20 State: c=constant k=key n=nonce
```

ie. the block counter is just being replaced with the extra bits of the nonce.

I note that the method I'm using to make it work in the first example does `pack('V', $counter)` which gives 01000000 instead of 00000001 so it kinda feels like maybe I need to do `strrev` on those first four bytes but that didn't help (see the commented out line in the second code block).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1241/4520 for a more extended discussion of which SE network this question ought to live at